# How to call a C# method that makes a Transaction from JS

Tags: javascript, c#, transactions

I have a question... I want to call a C# method that does the following

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("Transaccion")]
        public void TransactionCombustible(Models_Custom.combustible combustible) {
            using var dbContextTransaction = contextCustom.Database.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                //contextCustom.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
                //    $"INSERT INTO ADM.parametros_combustible VALUES("
                //    );
                //contextCustom.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
                //    $"UPDATE ADM.combustible set activo = {activo} where id = {parametro.id_combustible}", activo, parametro.id_combustible
                //    );
                //contextCustom.SaveChanges();
                throw new Exception("test");
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
```

And i call it this way

```
    let guardarModificarCombustible = (combustible) => {
        console.log(combustible)
        fetch(urlController + "/Transaccion", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(combustible)
        }).then(() => {
            obtenerCombustibles();
            setMostrarModal(false);
        });
    }
```

The problem is that it does not work... Can I call the method by POST method? How is it?
Thx

I need a C# method to perform a SQL Transaction that receives a parameter from the JS fetch

Comment: *"The problem is that it does not work"* - Please be more specific.  How exactly does it fail?  When you debug, what exactly happens?

Comment: It's going to throw an exception because you're throwing one.